# How can I insert a new column into the database which has the label ‘1’/’2’/’3’/’4’ # based upon the quantile of another column?

Tags: sql, sqlite, julia

I am having an issue with inserting a column in the table. I already calculated quantile of the one of the column but how I a going to insert into a table?

```
.open books.db

ALTER TABLE booksCSV ADD COLUMN quantile_rank;

SELECT average_rating, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY average_rating DESC) AS quantile_rank FROM booksCSV;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the column, you can use a CTE as follows:

```
WITH cte as (SELECT rowid, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY average_rating DESC) AS qr FROM booksCSV)
UPDATE booksCSV
SET quantile_rank = (SELECT qr FROM cte 
                     WHERE booksCSV.rowid = rowid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually *don't* recommend doing this, because if the column you have in mind is just easily derived from the underlying table data, then it is best to not store it.  That being said, you might just be looking for an update here:

```
ALTER TABLE booksCSV ADD quantile_rank REAL;

UPDATE booksCSV b
SET quantile_rank = (SELECT t.quartile_rank
                     FROM (
                         SELECT id, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY average_rating DESC) AS quartile_rank
                         FROM booksCSV
                     ) t
                     WHERE t.id = b.id);
```

Comment: Error: misuse of window function NTILE()

Comment: I agreed with your idea, but the professor asks explicitly to me to have this column. I am getting this error now; I did some research but no luck, any idea? 

Error: misuse of window function NTILE()